# How do I open multiple instances of an app?

Tags: dock

I have a *.app

If I open it, from the dock, or from Finder, it opens.
I want to open ANOTHER second running instance.

If I open it, from the dock or from the Finder the second time, now it simply *focuses* it.

One Windows and Ubuntu you can simply hold CTRL and click it and a second instance will open. How do I do that on OSX?

NOTE: I tried the `open -n` trick and it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly happens when you do "open -n"? That should absolutely work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because OSX is just unix, you can use a terminal to run the original binary that's stored in the *.app directory. A la

`/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit &`

Keep in mind some applications use databases to store their data which may cause conflicts or loss of data.

If you don't want to use the terminal, then you can make a shortcut icon that runs this command using the built in **Automater** app

Comment: This is not working for most of the apps in macOS High Sierra. For example I have tried with Visual Studio Code

Comment: Why do you need another instance of the Code binary running?  Open another window.  Code is (shudder) an Electron app, and there is no monolithic binary that you can start.  A single running instance of Code has *nine* different binaries running from inside the application bundle.